# Highlighting changes in code

Tags: highlighting, code, comparison

I want to print code, preferably syntax highlighted, and then combine this with a diff where the included code is the newer version of the code. I want lines that have been added or changed to be highlighted or displayed normally, and for lines that have been unmodifed to be faded.

Currently I am including the code with the lstlisting package, but that doesn't give me a way to combine the diff to highlight changes.

Something like this would be great.

**Original File**

> foo
>   bar

**Modified File** (included in the LaTeX document)

> foo
>   bar2
>   baz

And the result in the document would be

> foo
>   **bar2**
>   **baz**

(except ideally the normal text will be faded and the bold text would be normal)

Comment: So you want this highlighting to be automatic?

Comment: Simple answer: That can't be done by LaTeX. Of course if you use some external scripts you can achieved this.

Comment: I'd be interested to know if/how this could be implemented using LuaLaTeX.

Comment: I was hoping to find something that combined pygments with some smart processing to do this. I expect it can't be done in pure latex.

Comment: This should be pretty simple via Python with Pygments and difflib. I'll throw together a minimal example, and then sometime in the next few days add a macro for this to the syntax highlighting portion of my [PythonTeX package](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex).

Answer (score 10):

Here's a Python script that will do the diff.  It's for Python 2.x, but should work under 3 with a little tweaking (codecs.open() -> open(), etc.).  You'll need to customize the treatment of added/modified and deleted lines to suit your preference.  I will add a macro for this to my PythonTeX package, but it will be at least a few days till I incorporate that and release a new version.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Read in two code files, compute diff, and output a highlighted version in TeX 
format.  Usage: diff2tex.py old_file new_file

'''

# Imports
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import sys
import codecs
import difflib
import re
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import get_lexer_by_name
from pygments.formatters import LatexFormatter


file_encoding = 'utf=8'
lexer = 'python'
formatter = LatexFormatter(style='default', texcomments=False, mathescape=False, linenos=True)

def pygmentize(expr):
    s = highlight(expr, get_lexer_by_name(lexer), formatter)
    # Strip Verbatim environment
    s = re.sub(r'\\begin{Verbatim}\[.+\]\n', '', s)
    s = re.sub(r'\\end{Verbatim}\n', '', s)
    return s

def same_wrapper(expr):
    return r'\colorbox{white}{\parbox{\linewidth}{' + expr.rstrip('\r\n') + '\\vphantom{fg}}}\n'

def new_wrapper(expr):
    return r'\colorbox{PaleGreen}{\parbox{\linewidth}{' + expr.rstrip('\r\n') + '\\vphantom{fg}}}\n'

def del_wrapper(expr):
    return r'\colorbox{LightPink}{\parbox{\linewidth}{' + expr.rstrip('\r\n') + '\\vphantom{fg}}}\n'


old_file = codecs.open(sys.argv[1], 'r', encoding=file_encoding)
new_file = codecs.open(sys.argv[2], 'r', encoding=file_encoding)
differ = difflib.Differ()
diff = differ.compare(old_file.readlines(), new_file.readlines())

result = []
for line in diff:
    if line.startswith('  '):
        line = re.sub('^  ', '', line)
        result.append(same_wrapper(pygmentize(line)))        
    elif line.startswith('+ '):
        line = re.sub('\+ ', '', line)
        result.append(new_wrapper(pygmentize(line)))
    elif line.startswith('- '):
        line = re.sub('- ', '', line)
        result.append(del_wrapper(pygmentize(line)))
    elif line.startswith('\? '):
        pass


# Create a header and footer for a sample .tex document
header = '''\\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\\usepackage{lmodern}
\\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\\usepackage{upquote}

\\begin{document}
'''

footer = '''
\\end{document}
'''

# Get the correct command to start the Verbatim environment
begin_verbatim = highlight(' ', get_lexer_by_name(lexer), formatter).split('\n',1)[0] + '\n'


out_file = codecs.open('diff.tex', 'w', encoding=file_encoding)
out_file.write(header)
# Need to get and write the Pygments macros
out_file.write(formatter.get_style_defs())
out_file.write('\n\n')
out_file.write(begin_verbatim)
out_file.write(''.join(result))
out_file.write('\\end{Verbatim}\n')
out_file.write(footer)
out_file.close()
```

We can give this two files.  The old version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
'''
A docstring
'''
def f(x): #Will edit this
    x = x + 1
    x = x**2 #Will delete this
    return x**2

f(x)
print('Done!')
```

And the new, edited file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
'''
A docstring
'''
def f_new(x):
    #Add a comment
    x = x + 1
    return x**2

f_new(x)
print('Done!')
```

Running `python diff2tex.py old.py new.py` yields a document that compiles to the following:

[image]

Comment: Very nice answer! `:)`

Comment: In fact, it works like a charm with Python3 as well ! I really appreciated this answer, thanks !